# "waitMsAvg" is always 0 for running BQ jobs?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

Every time I see my BQ job status through [the API](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs/get), it always returns 0 for `waitMsAvg` when the job is running.

After the job is finished, then I can see valid numbers for `waitMsAvg`.

Is it intended behavior, or is it a bug?

How can I see the values when the job is running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BigQuery query plan provides timing classification for each query stage wherein
[`waitMsAvg`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/query-plan-explanation#per-stage_timing_classification)is the avg time spent by workers to get scheduled.

You are getting `waitMsAvg` as 0 because your query is still running. Once the query job completes `waitMsAvg` will denote the average time worker spent waiting to be scheduled.